# python pandas loc return empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the subset dataframe using the below code:

```
dprev = "eiffel tower"

df.loc[df['place'] == dprev] -> returns empty

drandom = random.choice(df['place'].unique())

df.loc[df['place'] == drandom] -> returns the subset
```

why am i not seeing the same thing when `dprev` is string variable?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your DF?

Comment: Destination MinTime Max Time
Les Halles 18 32
Av. des Champs Elysees 23 27
Avenue Victoria, Paris, France 15 28
Aquarium Tropical, 293 Avenue Daumesnil, 75012 Paris 3 7
Avenue de la République, 75011 Paris, France 12 22
Bd Peripherique 8 16
Boulevard de l'hspital 9 18
Eiffel Tower View, 76 BIS rue de la Federation, 75015 Paris, France 23 23

Comment: sorry, just taken it from csv.

Comment: Can you post it in the que please?

Comment: Kindly edit your post and put the data in your post properly.

Comment: In your data , it is  "Eiffel Tower View" and you are checking "eiffel tower". Is your data correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using `str.contains` with `case=False`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

dprev = "eiffel tower"
df = pd.DataFrame({"place": ["eiffel tower", "Eiffel tower", "Hello"], "data":[1,2,3]})
print(df.loc[df['place'].str.contains(dprev, case=False)])
```

**Output:**

```
   data         place
0     1  eiffel tower
1     2  Eiffel tower
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh,
tried with the case = False, but ended with empty dataframe. To help further this time -
dprev = Avenue Victoria, Paris, France

Is the comma is creating issue?

Comment: Can you post a sample of you csv in your question... I am not able to understand the data in your comment.

Comment: Can you post your DF also?

Answer (score 0):

for this you don't have to use `df.loc`

```
dprev = "eiffel tower"

df[df['place'] == dprev]
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071908/7053679)

Comment: Hi Nihal,tried without loc, but still returns empty dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
dprev = "eiffel tower"
df = df.loc[df['place'].str.lower() == dprev]
```

or:

```
df = df.loc[df['place'].str.lower().str.contains(dprev)]
```